# Pass an aliased column into a function for use in data.table `by=` argument

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to be able to do lots of bulk processing on a data.table grouped by different attributes.

I have a function which allows this to be done by passing it a string for the column intended to be grouped:

```
library(data.table)

myaggfunction<-function(mydt,aggcol,type){
  mydt[,lapply(.SD, sum), by=aggcol][,Type:=type]
}

myaggfunction(as.data.table(iris),"Species","Test")[]
```

However, some columns need to be aliased in the output. I know I can pass a string to `by` but how do you pass a list equivalent that does not get evaluated at the function parameter level e.g.

```
myaggfunction(as.data.table(iris),list(IrisSpecies=Species),"Test")[]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `substitute` to get the unevaluated expression and pass it on to the `by` in `data.table`.

```
library(data.table)

myaggfunction<-function(mydt,aggcol,type){
  aggcol <- substitute(aggcol)
  mydt[,lapply(.SD, sum), by=aggcol][,Type:=type]
}

myaggfunction(as.data.table(iris),"Species","Test")[]
myaggfunction(as.data.table(iris),list(IrisSpecies=Species),"Test")[]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Made a suggested edit that includes the removal of `eval`. I'm probably missing some important concept but without the `eval` it still runs fine - perhaps you could elaborate on it's use in this context?

Comment: @StephLocke, the by-expression is internally evaluated. However, I'd recommend to be explicit and use `eval()`, so that it's easier to understand what's going on. You don't need to `substitute()`. Just directly use `eval(aggcol)`.